# datatable scrollbar sometimes disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

```js
   $(selector).DataTable({
            scrollX: true,
            autoWidth: false,
    });
```

this is my table initializing part.

```js
const bindDataToTable = function({data = [], ...rest}) {
  const table = $("#table").DataTable();
  table.clear().draw();
  table.rows.add(data).draw();
  
    return Promise.resolve(Object.assign(
        {data: data},
        rest
    ));
}
```

this is part of binding data to table. 
Each time I click the pagination, repeat whether or not there is a scroll bar. 
I want the x-axis scroll bar to be fixed.

[here is Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohoroyoi/9mcgxhwk/2/)

Comment: Will you be able to put your code with html in a fiddle or snippet?

Comment: @JerdineSabio [here you can see](https://jsfiddle.net/ohoroyoi/9mcgxhwk/2/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work. When someone asks you for a fiddle they mean a working example and not just boldly copy and paste your code without a second thought.

Comment: Sorry, the ajax data setting was ambiguous. @IslamElshobokshy

Answer (score 1):

The scroll bar disappears intermittently whenever the pagination is clicked.

This fix resolves the problem.

```css
.dataTables_scrollHead {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100% !important;
}
.dataTables_scrollBody {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```